# Table does not show up in another schema

Tags: sql, oracle, schema, privileges

I am using the sql developer and so far I have a schema class `ADMIN` with all the tables inside it and another schema which is called `TEST`. I granted `select` on all tables for the user `TEST` in the `SCHEMA TEST`:

```
GRANT select on ADMIN.TABLE1 to TEST
```

The privilege is granted successfully, but when I connect as user `TEST`, I cannot see the table in the SQL Developer.

What do I have to do so this table shows up for the user `TEST`?
Both tables are located on the same tablespace but I think that this is irrelevant.

Comment: As user TEST, are you attempting to view the table in the TEST schema, or under the ADMIN schema?  Granting select will not add the table to the TEST schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table still exists in the ADMIN schema.  Granting read access to TEST does not make it appear in the TEST schema.  While logged in as TEST you will be able to query the table and if you navigate to the ADMIN schema you will see it there.  If you really want to see it in the TEST schema you can create a SYNONYM.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the explorer view of the schema in SQL Developer, there should be an item called "Other Users" (maybe "Other Schemas", can't recall for sure), under which you can view objects in other schemas that your schema has access to.